# Entity Framework Core 8 throws "Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor" error

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-8.0, ef-core-7.0, ef-core-8.0

Recently I have migrated my project from .NET 6 to .NET 8.

I have used Migrate Assistant to upgrade my project, I am able to build solution with .NET 8 packages. I can see only following packages are upgraded in my solution.

**Old Packages**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.8" />
```

**My Upgraded packages**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.3" />
```

I ran solution solution to test my code, but when code related to EntityFrameworkCore executes it throws following error. Did not found any specific documentation to fix this error, I am reaching out here, someone faces same issue or what is the solution ? Thanks for your help in advance.

**System.MissingMethodException
HResult=0x80131513
Message=Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type,** Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.

Comment: Do you have a full [mre]? Can you please at least share the full csproj file?